# how to make ImageView invisible when clicked

Tags: android

I'm new to the developers world and also to the eclipse IDE.. I'm trying to create a simple app that when you clicked the image, the image clicked will then become invisible

Here's the java code:

```
package com.example.capstone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Levelone extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{


        Button nextlevel;
        Button Main;
        ImageButton eagle;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(onSavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.levelone);
        nextlevel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNextlvl);
        nextlevel.setOnClickListener(this);
        Main = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMain);
        Main.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg0.getId()==R.id.imgEagle)
                {
                        eagle = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgEagle);
                eagle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

        }

}
```

Comment: @ uʍop ǝpısdn Your name is really creative!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `onCreate` put this

```
eagle = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgEagle);
eagle.setOnClickListener(this);
```

You forgot to define `eagle` button with appropriate widget from your layout and didn't attach `click` event handler to `eagle`.

and in `onClick`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.imgEagle:
            eagle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;

        case R.id.btnMain:
            //do something else
        break;

        case R.id.btnNextlvl:
            //do something else     
        break;  
    }
}
```

It's good to use `switch` to avoid number of `if-else` statements. And it makes code more readable also.

Comment: That's not a good answer, either for the OP of for anyone else coming along in the future.  What did you change and why?

Comment: @Simon why it's not a good answer? Is something wrong or is it that I should've given more explanation ? Let me know and I'll try to improve.

Answer (score 2):

You're not binding the `click` event to the image.

```
    eagle.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Use `findById` in `onCreate`, just as you did with `Main`, to locate `eagle`. The rest of the code should work unchanged, although using `findById` again in `onClick` is not necessary, you can just use `(ImageButton) arg0` or the `eagle` reference.

Comment: i think you want to say use `findViewById` because there is no such method with `findById` name